# Calling JPagination with limit function in ajax-accordion's page

Tags: php, ajax, joomla, accordion

Good day, everyone!

Here's the problem I recently encounter. I've used joomla template for my site. Then in the `views` directory I have a page that calls for a lists of employees. I've used `ajax-accordion` for this. So the names of the employees will serve as the header, then once the user clicked the `+` button beside it the rest of the personal details about each employees will collapse.

I have this jpagination inside `includes` directory outside of the `views` directory. Problem is, am new to joomla. And I only know how to do `pagination with limit links` when using a database. This was new to me, as we all know joomla uses `directories` instead.

I tried to call on the `JPagination` function inside the page from the `views` directory but it failed. Either the page won't load or the `accordion` won't work. Any idea how to get this done?
Is it really possible to combine `jpagination with limits` and `ajax-accordion` that comes from two different directories? Thanks for those who'll give light to this matter.

Here is the example output of what am trying to achieve:
[image]
Note: Imagine each name will trigger the `ajax-accordion` once clicked.

Answer (score 0):

DataTables Ajax sourced data below api helpful for you 
[Datatables Ajax](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

Comment: thanks sir. This will surely help if I want to use ajax for pagination. However, my problem is related with `Joomla`.